# Why can I not call on state in the render of a component after fetching data using fetch with React Native

Tags: react-native

Fairly new to React. Really new to react native. I know you should be able to reference state object in render method but when I try I get an error that is undefined. "Cant get variable of undefined" I want to set up a page that details each entry by id and the fetch method returns the details regarding each venue. I console this.state.data[0].venueName above and it logs out but when I try to reference it in the  component it says its undefined.

```
class BreweryDetailScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          data: []
      };
  }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.getBrewDeetsHandler();
    }

    getBrewDeetsHandler = () => {fetch('api url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          itemID: this.props.navigation.state.params.id
        }),
      }) .then(res => res.json())
      .then(myJson => {
          this.setState({
          data: myJson
        });
        console.log(this.state.data[0].venueName)
      })
     .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };

    render() { 
      return (
          <Text>{this.state.data[0].venueName}</Text>     
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the loading phase!

you can try to define an `isLoading: true` state which will change to `false` when data have been loaded!

Also please do NOT make API request in `componentWillMount()` and use `componentDidMount()` instead!

look at this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

class BreweryDetailScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBrewDeetsHandler();
  }

  getBrewDeetsHandler = () => {
    fetch('api url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        itemID: this.props.navigation.state.params.id
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(myJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: myJson
        });
        console.log(this.state.data[0].venueName);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='red' />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <Text>{this.state.data[0].venueName}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default BreweryDetailScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few good practices are,**

Don't call API in `componentWillMount`,

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getBrewDeetsHandler();
}
```

To call API make use of `componentDidMount`,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getBrewDeetsHandler();
}
```

API call is `async`, you won't be able to get data directly after API call because API call will take some time to execute and till that time your component will get render and you will get `undefined` error for your `state`.

You can make use of `asyn/await` for API call,

```
getBrewDeetsHandler = async () => {
   await fetch('api url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          itemID: this.props.navigation.state.params.id
        }),
      }) .then(res => res.json())
      .then(myJson => {
          this.setState({
          data: myJson
        }, ()=> console.log(this.state.data[0].venueName));//Callback in setState

      })
     .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
```

After setting state, you won't be able to do `console.log` with new state value, because `setState` is also `async`, make use of [`callback`](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) in `setState` to `console.log` data, as I did above.

When you try to use `state`, do always check if `state` value exists,

```
<Text>{this.state.data && this.state.data[0].venueName}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

because setState is an asynchronous operation and you are trying to access to state immediately after setState. please try this one.

```
this.setState({
      data: myJson
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.data[0].venueName); });
```

the second parameter of 'setState' method is a callback function which will be run after changing the state.